# using htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget to incorporate external js libraries for a new package to go into a shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I have been impressed by the `slick` javascript library (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and want to incorporate it into my shiny apps/flexboard pages.

I would like to use the `htmlwidgets` package in R incorporate the slick js library, so have started by trying to create a package as is suggested in the online documentation (http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html), by carrying out the following...

```
devtools::create("slick")              
setwd("slick")                          
htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("slick")
```

I downloaded the js library from https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/archive/1.6.0.zip

and placed it into the structure of the package so that I have a file structure that looks a bit like this.

```
R/
| slick.R

inst/
|-- htmlwidgets/
|   |-- slick.js
|   |-- slick.yaml
|   |-- lib/
|   |   |-- slick-1.6.0/
|   |   |   |-- slick/
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.min.js 
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.js
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.css
|   |   |   |   |-- slick-theme.css
```

My `slick.yaml` file looks like this...

```
dependencies:
  - name: slick
    version: 1.6.0
    src: htmlwidgets/lib/slick-1.6.0
    script:
        - slick/slick.min.js
        - slick/slick.js
    stylesheet: 
        - slick/slick.css
        - slick/slick-theme.css
```

But am really stuck as to how to adjust the `inst/htmlwidget/slick.js` file and the `R/slick.R` file in a way that can take a vector of urls and display them in a shiny app. The reason for this, is that it does not seem to match a similar input data concept as the example provided.

For reproducibility and to use the same URLs that are provided in the examples in the package, I am providing a vector of placeholder img urls that I would like to use as the contents. For each image in the carousel.

```
image_vec <- paste0("http://placehold.it/350x300?text=",seq(1:9))
```

Perhaps I might need to use something like this?...

```
lapply(image_vec,function(y){div(img(src=y))})
```

As always any help on this would be much appreciated.

*EDIT*

My new `slick.yaml` file looks like the following...after @NicE's answer post...am I missing something?

```
dependencies:
  - name: jquery
    version: 3.1.0
    src: htmlwidgets/lib
    script:
      - jquery-3.1.0.min.js
  - name: slick
    version: 1.6.0
    src: htmlwidgets/lib/slick-1.6.0
    script:
        - slick/slick.min.js
        - slick/slick.js
    stylesheet: 
        - slick/slick.css
        - slick/slick-theme.css
```

and now my file structure looks like the following:

```
R/
| slick.R

inst/
|-- htmlwidgets/
|   |-- slick.js
|   |-- slick.yaml
|   |-- lib/
|   |   |-- jquery-3.1.0.min.js
|   |   |-- slick-1.6.0/
|   |   |   |-- slick/
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.min.js 
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.js
|   |   |   |   |-- slick.css
|   |   |   |   |-- slick-theme.css
```

and my `/inst/htmlwidgets/slick.js` looks like the following

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'slick',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    // TODO: define shared variables for this instance
    // create new slick object witht the given id?
    var sl = new slick(el.id);



    return {

          renderValue: function(x) {
                    //add class to the div and center it
                    el.setAttribute("class",x.class);
                    el.style.margin = "auto";

                    //add images to the div
                    content='';    
                    for(var image in x.message)
                    {
                      content += '<div><img src="' + x.message[image] + '"/></div>';
                    }
                    el.innerHTML = content;

                    //initialize the slider.
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("."+x.class).slick(x.options);      
                    });

      },

      resize: function(width, height) {

        // TODO: code to re-render the widget with a new size

      }

    };
  }
});
```

Comment: is your project hosted on github?

Comment: yes...https://github.com/hmaeda/slick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt, using `htmlwidgets_0.6`:

For the dependencies, the `yaml` file looks the same, I just added jQuery above `slick`:

```
dependencies:
  - name: jquery
    version: 3.1.0
    src: htmlwidgets/lib
    script:
      - jquery-3.1.0.min.js
  - name: slick ...
```

You can get it [here](https://jquery.com/download/) and put it in the `lib` folder.

In the `slick.R` file, you need to change the arguments of the `slick` function to add options and change `x` to forward all the arguments to the JS code:

```
slick <- function(message, class="slick_slider", options = list(), width = NULL, height = NULL) {

  # forward options using x
  x = list(
    message = message,
    class = class,
    options = options
  )
...
```

In the `slick.js`, you mainly need to change the `renderValue` to add the images/content to the `div` and display the carousel:

```
renderValue: function(x) {
          //add class to the div and center it
          el.setAttribute("class",x.class)
          el.style.margin = "auto";

          //add images to the div
          content='';    
          for(var image in x.message)
          {
            content += '<div><img src="' + x.message[image] + '"/></div>';
          }
          el.innerHTML = content;

          //initialize the slider.
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("."+x.class).slick(x.options);      
          });

        }
```

Once you've installed it using `devtools::install()`, you can use it in a `shiny` app:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(slick)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test_slick <- renderSlick({    
    slick(paste0("http://placehold.it/350x300?text=",1:9),
          options=list(dots=TRUE,autoplay=TRUE))
})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("body {background-color: #2682d5}")),
  slickOutput('test_slick',width="350px",height="300px")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I get the following error when running the ui part..`Error in yaml.load(paste(readLines(input), collapse = "\n"), ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 11, column 5found character that cannot start any token at line 11, column 5`

Comment: If you copy paste the yaml from SO, I think the new lines or tab characters are wrong, I had to replace them manually for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion....now when running shinyApp() i just get a blue screen now...but no slick objects

Comment: inspecting the output and looking at the error is get the following `slick.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: slick is not defined`

Comment: you don't need the `var sl = new slick(el.id);` line, there is now `slick` object in the library. I'll try to put the code in on github when I have a sec.

Comment: here's a github repo with the code for this https://github.com/erardnicolas/slick